# Regex splitting up string only when the pipe is directly attached to a string with a equal sign

Tags: regex, kotlin

My regex skills are sadly quite low so was wondering how I could achieve this result:

```
test=hey
test2=hey | hey
test3=hey | hey | hey
test4=
test5=bye
```

Based on this string: `test=hey|test2=hey | hey|test3=hey | hey | hey|test4=|test5=bye` inside kotlin. Had before just `string.split("|")` but ran into a situation that the value could also contain the symbol | after the equal sign.

Comment: Okay so to clarify: You have a string like `test=hey|test2=hey | hey|test3=hey | hey | hey|test4=|test5=bye` and you want to extract `test=hey`, `test2=hey | hey` etc from it right?

Comment: You don't show examples of a pipe that should be considered disqualified in a split on pipe operation. Can you clarify ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try matching this regex in the string:

```
\\w+=.*?(?=\\|\\w+=|$)
```

[which you can try here](https://regex101.com/r/qoSYsa/1).

And here's how your code would look:

```kotlin
val text = "test=hey|test2=hey | hey|test3=hey | hey | hey|test4=|test5=bye"
val regex = Regex("\\w+=.*?(?=\\|\\w+=|$)")
val matches = regex.findAll(text)
matches.forEach() {
    result -> println(result.value)
}
```

---

### Explanation

`\\w+=.*?` matches one or more *word characters* followed by an equals sign and zero or more random characters
`(?=\\|\\w+=|$)` is a positive lookahead that ensures that the match so far is followed by either (a) a pipe, word characters and then an equals sign, or (b) the end of the string (`$`)

**Caveat: This lets your values have infinite pipes, but they CANNOT have an equals sign in them**